# can't able to update the maximum value and minimum value for rangeSlider manually

Tags: swift, slider, cocoapods, rangeslider

I am using the RangeSlider cocoa pod for slider option, the problem is I am not able to update the minimum value and the maximum value manually, and here is the code as well,

```
var sliderReference = RangeSlider(),

...

sliderReference.maximumValue = maximumPrice, 

sliderReference.minimumValue = minimumPrice
```

and the error I get when I run the code is

> Assertion failed: RangeSlider: minimumValue should be lower than maximumValue

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Is `minimumPrice` lower than `maximumPrice`? What are their values?

Comment: minimumPrice value is 9 and maximumPrice value is 2750

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the cocoa pod try using this line here.

```
sliderReference.scaleMaxValue = maximumValue
sliderReference.scaleMinValue = minimumValue
```

Comment: has this helped your problem?\